# Do we use XCTAssertEqual or XCTAssertEqualObject for dispatch_queue_t in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I know that `dispatch_queue_t` is a c struct, and not an NSObject. So should we use `XCTAssertEqual` or `XCTAssertEqualObject`? Will it be possible when we have 2 different pointers to the same queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`dispatch_queue_t`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatch_queue_t/) is not a struct. It is a `NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue>`. (There is an environment variable which can be used to control whether it is an object or not, but nowadays it almost always is an object.)

One should be wary of using any form of equality to determine if you are on the right queue because, if nothing else, one queue can target another. In our code, we don’t test the value of the queue, but rather tend to use [`dispatch_assert_queue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1642201-dispatch_assert_queue) (or [`dispatchPrecondition(.onQueue())`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780605-dispatchprecondition/) in Swift).

The other alternative, if this is your own custom queue, is to [`dispatch_queue_set_specific`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452967-dispatch_queue_set_specific) and then [`dispatch_queue_get_specific`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453067-dispatch_queue_get_specific).

Comment: what do you mean by one queue can target another?

Comment: `let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "Two", target: queue1)` will run tasks dispatched on `queue2` on `queue1`. It’s an advanced way to minimize context switches or employ a [mutual exclusion queue](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/706/?time=1236).